# Search filenames for a list of patterns and copy to destination

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of patterns in `filenames.txt`, and I want to search a folder for filenames containing the names.

`patterns.txt`:

```
254b    
0284ee    
001ty    
288qa
```

I want to search a folder for filenames containing any of these patterns in its filename and copy all found files to a destination directory.

So far i found a solution to view files as follows:

```
set -f; find ./ -type f \( $(printf -- ' -o - iname *%s*' $(cat patterns.txt) | cut -b4-) \); set +f
```

I can find all files based on the patterns on my `patterns.txt` file, but how do I copy them top a newfolder ?

Comment: Have you tried piping the result to xargs?
"| xargs -I {files} cp {files} /path/to/new/folder"

Comment: Do you need to handle files in sub directories. If YES, do you want all files copied to a `flat` destination, or do you have to maintain the hierarchy? (that is if there is ./a/b/c.txt, should it be (1) target/c.txt, or (2) target/a/b/c.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming target folder will not need to maintain the original hierarchy (or that the input directory does not have sub directories), using find, grep, and xargs should work:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  grep -z -i -F -f patterns.txt |
  xargs -0 -s1000 cp -t /new/folder
```

The sequence has the advantage of bulking the copy - will be efficient for large number of files. Using NUL to separate file name should allow any special character in the file name.